# Cómo redireccionar a otra vista o página en Angular 4

Tags: angular

Necesito saber cuál es la sintaxis en typescript para redireccionar a otra página o vista en Angular 4.

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te aconsejo que utilices las características de routing de Angular. Puedes activarlas utilizando:

```
ng new mi-aplicacion --routing true
```

Tendrás que definir un fichero de ruteo para el componente raíz (app-module) y para el resto de componentes sobre los que quieras enrutar (redirigir).

De esta manera podrás chequear tu variable booleana de login exitoso redirigiendo a un nuevo componente que contenga la parte privada.

Aún así te aconsejo que controles los enrutamientos con un token de sesión para mejorar la seguridad de tu aplicación.

Aquí tienes un enlace donde explica de manera sencilla como enrutar con Angular. http://academia-binaria.com/enrutado-con-angular2-el-nuevo-spa/

Comment: Gracias, es la misma sintaxis para Angular 4? Voy a checarla.